# Solution to the following diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, word-problem

I have the following problem:

A woman went to the supermarket to buy 12 liters of milk, some of which are whole and the others skimmed, for \$1200. If the whole milk is worth \$30 more per liter than the skimmed, and she bought the minimum of skimmed milk, How many liters would she have bought of each type?

I am having difficulties extracting the data from such type of questions. From my knowledge:

$$x \rightarrow \text{ whole milk, } \\
y\rightarrow \text{ skimmed milk, } \\
a \rightarrow \text{ price of whole milk, } \\
b \rightarrow \text{ price of skimmed milk. }$$

I gathered that:

$$x + y = 12 \implies y = 12 - x \rightarrow \text{ eq. 1 } \\
ax + by = 1200  \rightarrow \text{ eq. 2 } \\
a = b + 30  \rightarrow \text{ eq. 3 }$$

Substituting eq. 1 and 3 into eq. 2:

$$(b+30)x + b(12-x) = 1200 \\
bx + 30x + 12b - bx = 1200 \\
30x + 12b = 1200$$

$$mcd(30, 12) = 6 \implies \frac{30x}{6} + \frac{12b}{6} = \frac{1200}{6} \\
5x + 2b = 200$$

Then:

$$x_0 = \frac{200 - 2y_0}{5} \\
y_0 = 5 \implies x_0 = \frac{200 - 2(5)}{5} = \frac{200 - 10}{5} = \frac{190}{5} = 38 \\
x_0 = 38$$

Therefore:

$$(x_9, y_0) = (38, 5)$$

General Solution:

$$(38-2k, 5+5k)$$

Would that be the way to go? From here, how do I proceed?

Comment: $100$ dollars for a litre of milk!!!

Comment: @Raffaele how did you come about this?

Comment: I solved the system and then I examined all the possibility for the $b$ variable. I can add details how I solved the system, if you want

Comment: I made some mistake in the previous answer. Now it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $a = b + 30$ and $x + y = 12\to y=12-x$

substituting in the 2nd equation we have

$(b+30)x+b(12-x)=1200$

$bx +30x+12b-bx=1200$

$30x+12b=1200$

$5x+2b=200$

$x=\dfrac{200-2b}{5}$

$y=12-\dfrac{200-2b}{5}=\dfrac{2b-140}{5}$

and finally the solution

$$a= b+30,x= \frac{200-2b}{5},y= \frac{2b-140}{5}$$
$200-2b>0$ then must be $b<100$ and $2b-140>0$ because $y$ must be positive
so must be $b>70$

Thus must be $70<b<100$ and divisible by $5$ so the solution is

$
\begin{array}{l|l|l|l}
a & b & x & y\\
\hline
 105& 75 &10&2\\
110&80&8&4\\
115&85&6&6\\
120&90&4&8\\
125&95&2&10\\ 
\end{array}
$

Hope this helps

Comment: Definitely, but unfortunately I made a mistake in $eq. 1$ where $x+y=12b$ is actually $x+y=12$. Do you think you can adjust your answer to suite? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have tried this is my last version :)